# Enumerate affecting text break across pages

Tags: tables

I am having problems with text breaking across pages in my document. From the picture, you can see that 'Section 2.2.2' is positioned poorly.

The problem seems to be due to the contents of Table 3.

I include 2 MWE's with pictures. The first MWE shows the problem. The second MWE contains the same code but with a different Table 3. The only difference between the two tables is the number of text strings.

Can someone suggest a reason and solution for this please?

MWE 1 (problem):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}%this changes the page geometry i.e. margins left, right, top and bottom
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype,setspace,amsmath,SIunits,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell,ltablex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library}
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
    \sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \center % Centre everything on the page

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{\LARGE title}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

    \textsc{\Large title}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

    %\textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------

    \HRule\\[0.4cm]

    {\huge\bfseries title}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document

    \HRule\\[1.5cm]

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        %\begin{flushleft}
            %\large
            %\textit{Author}\\
            %Kevin\textsc{To} % Your name
        %\end{flushleft}
    %\end{minipage}
    ~
    %\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        %\begin{flushright}
            %\large
            %\textit{Supervisor}\\
            %Professor Ivan \textsc{Parkin} % Supervisor's name
        %\end{flushright}
    %\end{minipage}

    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
        {\large\textit{}}\\
        \textsc{} % Your name

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

    {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Logo
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\vfill\vfill
    %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{placeholder.jpg}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page

\end{titlepage}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\widenhead[\marginparwidth][0pt]{0pt}{\marginparwidth}
\headrule
\sethead[~\color{black}\enspace][][]{}{}{\color{black}\enspace}
\setfoot[{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\thepage~}\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}}][][]{}{}{\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{~\thepage}
}
}%

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Aim}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Scope}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{User interface components under study}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{50 mm} p{80mm}}
        \toprule
        Component & Rationale \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        Sign up & To achieve full functionality in the applications, sign up is necessary. As such, a painless process would encourage positive user experience and improve retention.\\
        Learning to map & A straightforward training process, where concepts are easy to grasp further enhances the user experience.\\
         Progress review & A feature in many citizen science applications, is the ability to track progress and review achievements. This feature is important for providing users with a sense of achievement and facilitates those who are competitive.\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
\end{table}

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Overview}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\section{Method}   
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Heuristic evaluation}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Shneiderman's 'Eight Golden Rules of Interface Design'}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{30mm} p{80mm} }
        \toprule
        No.&Heuristic\\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        1&Strive for consistency\\
        2&Enable frequent users to use shortcuts\\
        3&Offer informative feedback\\
        4&Design dialogue to yield closure\\
        5&Offer simple error handling\\
        6&Permit easy reversal of actions\\
        7&Support internal locus of control\\
        8&Reduce short-term memory load\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier

\subsection{Cognitive walkthrough}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

\subsubsection{Goals, tasks and actions}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            X
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
            X
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
        \midrule
        Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
        &   Task 1:  Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Mapswipe: Find Mapswipe on Missingmaps.

            PRN: Find the PRN from the Zooniverse.
            \item Join the project.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate the ease in learning to map
        &   Task 2:  Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
        \addlinespace
        Contribute data
        &   Task 3: Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Begin mapping.
            \item Mapswipe: Classify a building.

            PRN: Classify a Road Blockage.
            \item Review maps classified.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
        & -- & --                   \\
        \bottomrule
        \vspace{-18mm}%needed otherwise the table gets lost between pagebreaks. 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Evaluation of user and interface interaction}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals?
    \item Is the action visible?
    \item Will the user recognise the action as the right one?
    \item Will the user understand the feedback?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

MWE 2:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}%this changes the page geometry i.e. margins left, right, top and bottom
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype,setspace,amsmath,SIunits,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell,ltablex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library}
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
    \sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \center % Centre everything on the page

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{\LARGE title}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

    \textsc{\Large title}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

    %\textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------

    \HRule\\[0.4cm]

    {\huge\bfseries title}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document

    \HRule\\[1.5cm]

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        %\begin{flushleft}
            %\large
            %\textit{Author}\\
            %Kevin\textsc{To} % Your name
        %\end{flushleft}
    %\end{minipage}
    ~
    %\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        %\begin{flushright}
            %\large
            %\textit{Supervisor}\\
            %Professor Ivan \textsc{Parkin} % Supervisor's name
        %\end{flushright}
    %\end{minipage}

    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
        {\large\textit{}}\\
        \textsc{} % Your name

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

    {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Logo
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\vfill\vfill
    %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{placeholder.jpg}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page

\end{titlepage}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\widenhead[\marginparwidth][0pt]{0pt}{\marginparwidth}
\headrule
\sethead[~\color{black}\enspace][][]{}{}{\color{black}\enspace}
\setfoot[{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\thepage~}\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}}][][]{}{}{\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{~\thepage}
}
}%

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Aim}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Scope}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{User interface components under study}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{50 mm} p{80mm}}
        \toprule
        Component & Rationale \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        Sign up & To achieve full functionality in the applications, sign up is necessary. As such, a painless process would encourage positive user experience and improve retention.\\
        Learning to map & A straightforward training process, where concepts are easy to grasp further enhances the user experience.\\
         Progress review & A feature in many citizen science applications, is the ability to track progress and review achievements. This feature is important for providing users with a sense of achievement and facilitates those who are competitive.\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
\end{table}

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Overview}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\section{Method}   
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Heuristic evaluation}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Shneiderman's 'Eight Golden Rules of Interface Design'}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{30mm} p{80mm} }
        \toprule
        No.&Heuristic\\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        1&Strive for consistency\\
        2&Enable frequent users to use shortcuts\\
        3&Offer informative feedback\\
        4&Design dialogue to yield closure\\
        5&Offer simple error handling\\
        6&Permit easy reversal of actions\\
        7&Support internal locus of control\\
        8&Reduce short-term memory load\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier

\subsection{Cognitive walkthrough}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

\subsubsection{Goals, tasks and actions}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            X
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
            X
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
        \midrule
        Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
        &   Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Teast A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

            Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate the ease in learning to map
        &   Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
        \addlinespace
        Contribute data
        &   Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \item Test A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

            Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
        & -- & --                   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Evaluation of user and interface interaction}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals?
    \item Is the action visible?
    \item Will the user recognise the action as the right one?
    \item Will the user understand the feedback?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Picture 1 - problem
[image]

Picture 2
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure of a reason yet but you can fix things by putting `\clearpage` before `\subsubsection{Evaluation of user and interface interaction}`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using simple margin=2.5cm in `geometry` package as `\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype,setspace,amsmath,SIunits,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell,ltablex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library}
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
    \sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \center % Centre everything on the page

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{\LARGE title}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

    \textsc{\Large title}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

    %\textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------

    \HRule\\[0.4cm]

    {\huge\bfseries title}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document

    \HRule\\[1.5cm]

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        %\begin{flushleft}
            %\large
            %\textit{Author}\\
            %Kevin\textsc{To} % Your name
        %\end{flushleft}
    %\end{minipage}
    ~
    %\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        %\begin{flushright}
            %\large
            %\textit{Supervisor}\\
            %Professor Ivan \textsc{Parkin} % Supervisor's name
        %\end{flushright}
    %\end{minipage}

    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
        {\large\textit{}}\\
        \textsc{} % Your name

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

    {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Logo
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\vfill\vfill
    %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{placeholder.jpg}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page

\end{titlepage}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\widenhead[\marginparwidth][0pt]{0pt}{\marginparwidth}
\headrule
\sethead[~\color{black}\enspace][][]{}{}{\color{black}\enspace}
\setfoot[{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\thepage~}\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}}][][]{}{}{\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{~\thepage}
}
}%

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Aim}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Scope}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{User interface components under study}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{50 mm} p{80mm}}
        \toprule
        Component & Rationale \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        Sign up & To achieve full functionality in the applications, sign up is necessary. As such, a painless process would encourage positive user experience and improve retention.\\
        Learning to map & A straightforward training process, where concepts are easy to grasp further enhances the user experience.\\
         Progress review & A feature in many citizen science applications, is the ability to track progress and review achievements. This feature is important for providing users with a sense of achievement and facilitates those who are competitive.\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
\end{table}

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Overview}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\section{Method}   
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\subsection{Heuristic evaluation}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Shneiderman's 'Eight Golden Rules of Interface Design'}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering
    \small
    % your table
    \hspace*{-18mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ p{30mm} p{80mm} }
        \toprule
        No.&Heuristic\\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        1&Strive for consistency\\
        2&Enable frequent users to use shortcuts\\
        3&Offer informative feedback\\
        4&Design dialogue to yield closure\\
        5&Offer simple error handling\\
        6&Permit easy reversal of actions\\
        7&Support internal locus of control\\
        8&Reduce short-term memory load\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier

\subsection{Cognitive walkthrough}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

\subsubsection{Goals, tasks and actions}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. 

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            X
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
            X
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
        \midrule
        Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
        &   Task 1:  Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Mapswipe: Find Mapswipe on Missingmaps.

            PRN: Find the PRN from the Zooniverse.
            \item Join the project.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate the ease in learning to map
        &   Task 2:  Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
        \addlinespace
        Contribute data
        &   Task 3: Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Begin mapping.
            \item Mapswipe: Classify a building.

            PRN: Classify a Road Blockage.
            \item Review maps classified.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
        & -- & --                   \\
        \bottomrule
        \vspace{-18mm}%needed otherwise the table gets lost between pagebreaks. 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Evaluation of user and interface interaction}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals?
    \item Is the action visible?
    \item Will the user recognise the action as the right one?
    \item Will the user understand the feedback?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Although the code works, you have removed the original page margin dimensions which were `\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}`.